# Prevent a tag from redirecting when the listener is on the document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I prevent the default behaviour of an `a` tag if a user clicks on it, when the event listener is on the `document`.

My code looks like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  document.addEventListener('click', displayModal);
}

const displayModal = (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    // issue with the line below
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  }
};
```

Comment: cool, Yeah it is just normal react :-)

Comment: 'a' needs to be capitalised. `if (e.target.tagName === 'A')`

Comment: @Lewis good shout, still think there is an issue. Updated the question but good spot

Comment: The event that you want to prevent the default action of is still `e`, not `e.parent` (the latter is not even an event object, but an HTMLElementObject.) You want `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @04FS hmm, if I do `e.preventDefault();` it doesn't work. I believe this is because the click event is on the `document` and not the `a` tag. Make sense? I updated the question to be `e.preventDefault();` as it doesn't work

Comment: No, it is still the same event, you are only catching it when it has bubbled up to document. Add some debug statements or jump into it using the dev tools debugger, to figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: Based on your last comment, you could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182329/reverse-event-bubbling-in-javascript) that discusses reverse event bubbling, and stop propagation from the dom down rather than the *a* up.

Comment: passing `true` as the third argument fixes it

Comment: What about `e.stopPropagation();`